# Jquery ajax is giving me a 404 not found error

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have the following code:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
    function loadPhotos(folderName){
            var folder = "assets/photos/"+folderName+"/";
            $.ajax({
                url : folder,
                success: function (data) {
                    $(data).find("a").attr("href", function (i, val) {
                        if( val.match(/\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$/) ) { 
                            $("body").append( "<img src='"+ folder + val +"'>" );
                        } 
                    });
                }
            });
          }
</script>
</head>

<html>
 <div onclick="loadPhotos('7thAnnual')">7th Annual</div>
</html>
```

For some odd reason when I click on the div, the loadPhotos function throws a 404 not found error on the ajax call.... but the directory that it is saying it can't find, does exist.

For the record I am running this on localhost (http://127.0.0.1:8020/).

the directory structure is Ljf/assets/photos/7thAnnual ....

so the full path would be http://127.0.0.1:8020/Ljf/assets/photos/7thAnnual

the 7thAnnual directory holds all the images

Any thoughts?

Comment: What is your directory structure?

Comment: What have you done to debug this?  Have you tried just opening a new window with the URL created for the ajax call?  It looks like you are just getting a directory list correct?

Comment: Check in developer tools, under network tab, that exactly what call is being made

Comment: jsve... I added more info in my initial post for you at the bottom

Comment: RudyTheHunter ... I can use the url plus one of the images in the browser itself and the image comes up.... if I post the url directory without the image file I get "File /assets/photos/7thAnnual/ not found"

Comment: You should try absolute path starting from Ljf folder to see that your relative path is ok.

Comment: you do mean like so?  `var folder = "Ljf/assets/photos/"+folderName+"/";`? ..   tried that already... didn't work

Comment: also, if it helps, I am running this from Aptana

Comment: What if you just type the link into your browser and hit enter? 404 or...? Also try `var folder = "/Ljf/assets/photos/"+folderName+"/"` (leading `/`)

Comment: the error i actually get is this: GET `http://127.0.0.1:8020/Lfj/assets/photos/7thAnnual/ 404 (Not Found)`...  

if I place `http://127.0.0.1:8020/Lfj/assets/photos/7thAnnual/1.jpg` in the browser, it shows up fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay.... so it seems that I have to fully qualify the name in the url like so:

```
var folder = "127.0.0.1:8020/Ljf/assets/photos/7thAnnual";
```

instead of using just:

```
var folder = "Ljf/assets/photos/7thAnnual"
```

This answer brings a

> "Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http,
>   data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource."

which is a different issue than this post, but it does solve the

> 404 not found

So I'll mark it as the answer

Comment: then again.... this solution doesn't work in FireFox.... I still get a 404 not found error there

Answer (score 0):

You must create the directory assets/photos/7thAnnual/. Be sure you did that

Comment: the directory does exist

Answer (score 0):

If you run this in chrome and open the nifty little inspector

(right click on the background somewhere, choose inspect, then go to the network tab on the inspection window)

then click the div that should trigger the ajax, it should show you the path it tries to get to. (on your little network panel at the very bottom)

Make sure that the path looks right

Look at the response to see if there is any other potentially useful info

let me know what you find!

Comment: http://127.0.0.1:8020/Ljf/assets/photos/7thAnnual/ is the directory where it fails..... it throws the 404... but the directory exists, so I am not sure why it is failing

Comment: and you can navigate to that in your browser?

Comment: not the directory itself.... but if i add an image file like this: 127.0.0.1:8020/Ljf/assets/photos/7thAnnual/1.jpg .... it works

Comment: And in your navigation panel you get the full path with the image filename? Do you need to add `.jpg` to your onclick or your function?

`<div onclick="loadPhotos('7thAnnual.jpg')">7th Annual</div>`

or

Comment: Actually Im not sure how
`
var folder = "assets/photos/"+folderName+"/";
            $.ajax({
                url : folder,`

is supposed to work, thats the part you are having trouble with, the folder isnt something that can be navigated to if you are using rails or something to host the assets on the backend, Im not sure what the rest of your server is though

Comment: the idea of the 7thAnnual parameter is to provide the folder name that the photos are in.

Comment: I am doing this all locally... I assume it is using IIS locally.

Comment: also, if it helps, I am running this from Aptana